# How to convert List<object> to Json format and populate <tbody> in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, json

I really cannot find any sample how to convert `List<object>` to Json format and populate `<tbody>` in C#?

List result = new List ();

```
MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
MyClass m2 = new MyClass();

result.Add(m1);
result.Add(m2);

    return Json(???);


 $.post("/Tradeshow/AddTradeShowDetail", {
        startdate: $('#cstartdate').val(),
        enddate: $('#cenddate').val(),
        location: $('#clocation').val(),
        speakerid: $('#TradeshowSpeakers').val(),
        isnonspeaker: value
    },
                 function (data) {

                     if (data.length > 0) {

                             // Populate <tbody> ???

                      }
                 });
```

Comment: What's `MyClass`? Is it serializable? Also, is it safe to assume MVC given the `return Json()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087312/how-to-convert-a-listt-to-specific-json-format check this

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366183/639960

Comment: What is "tody" supposed to mean? Today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**action**

```
var result = new List<MyClass>();
MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
MyClass m2 = new MyClass();

result.Add(m1);
result.Add(m2);

return Json(result);
```

**js**

```
 $.post("/Tradeshow/AddTradeShowDetail", {
    startdate: $('#cstartdate').val(),
    enddate: $('#cenddate').val(),
    location: $('#clocation').val(),
    speakerid: $('#TradeshowSpeakers').val(),
    isnonspeaker: value
}, function(data) {

    if (data && data.d && data.d.length > 0) {
        var rows = $.map(data.d,function(item) {
            return ('<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td></tr>');
        }).join('');
        $('tbody').html(rows);
    }
});
```

Check if the list is in `data.d` when it comes back.  If not, just process `data`