# saving data in windows store apps

Tags: c#, sql, xml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a movie gallery application for windows 8, and I'm using C# and XAML. 
I have written my business logic and everything is working fine, but my problem is I have no idea how to store the data. I've watched couple of win 8 courses but none of them cover data storage in win 8!
As you might guess, my application have some Collection of objects, and if I could use Entity Framework, it would be so easy to store them in a database like SQL Server. but it's been pointed out to me that Entity Framework is not available in windows apps and using SQLLite is a little tedious, because it has no ORM!

I'm thinking saving them to xml might be a good idea! but I haven't work with xml yet, is there an easy and standard way to save and update collections of data(objects) to xml and retrieve them? like the way Entity Framework does that, when using SQL Database? something like an ORM?!

Comment: if you have few collections only, and objects are flat with few properties, serializing to xml or json may be manageable. otherwise, it may get overwhelming. XML/JSON serialization can be done using data contract serializer. you can refer some sample code in [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087312/how-to-convert-a-listt-to-specific-json-format). XML can be indented with appropriate writer. JSON - I did not find so.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to Entity Framework, but you can use a SQLite database to store your data. I don't have time to write everything out, but there are plenty of blogs on the topic:

[Using database in Windows Store apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2013/01/10/using-database-in-windows-store-apps-i.aspx)